# Remove subquery from query involving date between two other dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables first one is like this call this table `StartEndDates`

```
| StartDate    | EndDate    | SomeOtherData |
|2018-09-08    | 2018-09-23 | data 1        |
|2018-07-08    | 2018-08-01 | data 2        |
```

The other table is like this call this table `DataAndCreatedOn`

```
| Data   | CreatedOn  |
| 1.5    | 2018-09-20 | 
| 2.4    | 2018-07-15 |
| 3.5    | 2018-07-21 |
```

So now I have a query like this

```
Select sed.someotherdata
    , (select sum(data) 
       from DataAndCreatedOn 
       where CreatedOn between sed.StartDate and sed.EndDate) as total 
from StartEndDates sed
```

Is there a way to get rid of the subquery `(select sum(data) from DataAndCreatedOn where CreatedOn between sed.StartDate and sed.EndDate) as total` and put it as a join somehow?

Comment: Ezlo provides an answer and a warning. Give that warning extensive thought. Your current query returns every row in StartEndDates - even if there are multiple rows containing the same value of someotherdata.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JOIN` and a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    sed.someotherdata,
    SUM(d.data) as total
FROM
    StartEndDates sed
    LEFT JOIN DataAndCreatedOn d ON d.CreatedOn BETWEEN sed.StartDate and sed.EndDate
GROUP BY
    sed.someotherdata
```

However the rows of `StartEndDates` will be grouped (you might get less rows compared to your original query if you have duplicate values on `someotherdata`).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a CROSS APPLY if you really wanted to get rid of that subquery, although the execution plan is almost identical. As @EzLo pointed out, and as you will see from my example, if you have duplicate SomeOtherData it will alter your results based on if you do a LEFT JOIN or a CROSS APPLY. So it depends on what your are looking to get back from your query.  I would also pay attention to query performance:

```
CREATE TABLE #StartEndDates(StartDate  date, EndDate  date, SomeOtherData varchar(100))
CREATE TABLE #DateAndCreatedOn(Data decimal(10,4), CreatedOn date)

INSERT INTO #StartEndDates VALUES('2018-09-08', '2018-09-23', 'data 1')
INSERT INTO #StartEndDates VALUES('2018-07-08', '2018-08-01', 'data 2')
INSERT INTO #StartEndDates VALUES('2018-07-21', '2018-08-12', 'data 3')

--INSERT THIS ROW TO SEE DUPLICATE SomeOtherData
INSERT INTO #StartEndDates VALUES('2018-07-11', '2018-08-12', 'data 3')


INSERT INTO #DateAndCreatedOn VALUES(1.5,'2018-09-20')
INSERT INTO #DateAndCreatedOn VALUES(2.4,'2018-07-15')
INSERT INTO #DateAndCreatedOn VALUES(3.5,'2018-07-21')



--ORIGINAL QUERY
 Select sed.someotherdata
    , (select sum(data) 
       from #DateAndCreatedOn 
       where CreatedOn between sed.StartDate and sed.EndDate) as total 
from #StartEndDates sed


--LEFT JOIN QUERY
SELECT
    sed.someotherdata,
    SUM(d.data) as total
FROM
    #StartEndDates sed
    LEFT JOIN #DateAndCreatedOn d ON d.CreatedOn BETWEEN sed.StartDate and sed.EndDate
GROUP BY
    sed.someotherdata


--CROSS APPLY QUERY
 SELECT sed.SomeOtherData, x.SM
 FROM #StartEndDates sed
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Data) SM  from #DateAndCreatedOn d where d.CreatedOn between sed.StartDate and sed.EndDate) x
```